# Javascript, Fastest way to know if a certain value is in a array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [array.contains(obj) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)

Let's say I have an array = [0,8,5]

What is the fastest way to know if 8 is inside this one.. for example:

```
if(array.contain(8)){
 // return true
}
```

I found this : [Fastest way to check if a value exist in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571635/python-fastest-way-to-check-if-a-value-exist-in-a-array) (Python)

and this : [fastest way to detect if a value is in a set of values in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308191/fastest-way-to-detect-if-a-value-is-in-a-set-of-values-in-javascript)

But this don't answer to my question. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-21

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `indexOf()` to check whether value is exist or not

```
array.indexOf(8)
```

Sample Code,

```
var arr = [0,8,5];
alert(arr.indexOf(8))​; //returns key
```

## Update

**For IE support**

```
//IE support
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) { 
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj, start) {
         for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
             if (this[i] === obj) { return i; }
         }
         return -1;
    }
}

var arr = [0,8,5];
alert(arr.indexOf(8))
```

Comment: This of course assumes you're not using an old browser.

Comment: `Array.indexOf` doesn't work in IE < 9.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I checked on IE 8, it's working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/LhvwV/1/

Comment: @MuthuKumaran: no way. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: @MuthuKumaran: That's because that fiddle is using MooTools.  MooTools adds `Array.prototype.indexOf` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: oh that explains why it worked on IE.

Comment: Thanks to all for pointing it out. I updated my answer.

Comment: +1: MDC also recommends a more elaborate implementation though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/IndexOf#Compatibility

Comment: You should mention that if the item isn't in the array, `.indexOf()` returns -1

Comment: `.includes()` is actually faster than `.indexOf()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a indexOf() function

```
var fruits = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("a3");
```

The output will be: 2

Comment: `Array.indexOf` doesn't work in IE < 9.

Comment: Refer this answer for ie < 9 browser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744310/how-to-fix-array-indexof-in-javascript-for-ie-browsers

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` or you can try this:

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

Answer (score -1):

phpjs has a nice php's in_array function's port to javascript, you may use it

http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array/

see example:

```
in_array('van', ['Kevin', 'van', 'Zonneveld']);
```