# Stata - Subsetting: Fastest way to detect if a value is in a set of values in Stata

Tags: excel, stata, vba

Basically the same problem that this question contains but in Stata and for integer values.
([fastest way to detect if a value is in a set of values in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308191/fastest-way-to-detect-if-a-value-is-in-a-set-of-values-in-javascript))

Run the following code in Stata:

`set obs 9`

`generate var1 = 1 in 1`
`replace var1 = 2 in 2`
`replace var1 = 3 in 3`
`replace var1 = 4 in 4`
`replace var1 = 5 in 5`
`replace var1 = 6 in 6`
`replace var1 = 7 in 7`

`generate var2 = 6 in 1`
`replace var2 = 5 in 2`
`replace var2 = 4 in 3`
`replace var2 = 3 in 4`
`replace var2 = 2 in 5`
`replace var2 = 1 in 6`
`replace var2 = 58 in 7`
`replace var2 = 69 in 8`
`replace var2 = 51 in 9`

The idea is simple. If for example the value `5` (in `var1`) occurs in the set of all values contained in `var2`, I want to create `var3` and stick a `"yes"` (in newly created `var3`) next to the `5` in `var1` and `"no"` otherwise. So for example there would be a `"no"` (in newly created `var3`) next to `7` (in `var1`) because `7` isn't in any of the values contained in `var2`.

Comment: Dr. Cox, I have simplified my question. Thank you for your extremely prompt reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative method if a loop is somehow difficult to construct would be to use a merge:

```
clear
input float(var1 var2)
1  6
2  5
3  4
4  3
5  2
6  1
7 58
. 69
. 51
end

tempfile original
save `original'          * Save data (presumably you have this on disk already)

drop var1                * Keep only the key variable for the merge
rename var2 var1         * Rename for merge   

tempfile set2
save `set2'              * save file with only values from var2 in original set

use `original', clear

merge m:1 var1 using `set2'

drop if _merge == 2     * Drop new observations created for values only in var2

list, sepby(_merge)
```

Here, you will notice that the _merge variable created during the `merge` contains information on which values of var1 exist in var2. From this point it is somewhat trivial to `destring` and update the values to "yes" and "no", or to create a new variable conditional on the values of _merge.

Note also that the `merge` is likely to be significantly faster than a loop if you have a large dataset.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force method for doing this, if I understand correctly, is:

```
gen var3="no" 
local N=_N 

forval i=1/`N' { 
    replace var3 = "yes" if var1 == var2[`i']
}
```

If you're not wed to your current data structure, it will be more efficient just to loop through all of the values you're looking for:

```
gen var3="no" 
foreach i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 58 69 51 {
    replace var3 = "yes" if var1==`i'
}
```